# How to turn off split screen mode in Oreo?

Tags: 8.0-oreo, 8.1-oreo

I hate this feature because:

1. I don't use it
2. I often turn this on automatically

Any way this can be disabled? I've searched the net but nothing useful came up.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Step 1. Enter the Overview Screen. If you see the "Recents" button, tap on that to enter the Overview screen.

Step 2. Enable Split Screen Mode. Tap or long-press the icon near the top of the individual app's card until a submenu appears.

Step 3. Exit Split Screen Mode.

How to end your split-screen mode session?

While split-screen mode can come in handy, it’s definitely not something you want to use all the time. There are a few ways to get out of split-screen mode.

The first, and probably most simple, way to end split-screen mode is by long-tapping the split-screen app switching icon. This method automatically closes the secondary app at the bottom of your display.

Another way to end your split-screen mode session is simply by dragging the divider line all the way to the top or bottom of your display. This method allows you to select which app you prefer to keep open, as opposed to automatically selecting the app at the top of your screen.

Furthermore, there is [this thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/pixel/help/disable-multi-window-t3653528) which can help you too.

Comment: The question is about disabling splitscreen mode entirely (as in it can't be accessed anymore), not how to get out of a splitscreen.

Comment: I think their is no way to disable it till you don't have root access.